# Singleton class in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, singleton

I have to implement a Singleton class in JSF which reads a file, parses it and outputs another file. My question is, does it really make sense to create a Singleton class when there is the `ManagedBean`? As per my understanding of JSF, the ManagedBean itself is a Singleton class.

If I can indeed create a Singleton class, how does can I use with the JSF code since it always interacts with the ManagedBean?

Comment: A managed bean **IS NOT** a singleton class. Please explain your functional requirement in order to get accurate help.

Comment: Go through this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651132/jsf-singleton-vs-application-scoped-managed-bean-differences

Comment: How did you conclude that JSF ManagedBean is a singleton class?

Comment: Like as with many starters, your understanding of the meaning of "singleton" is completely wrong. This question is therefore not making much sense.